# If statement in MDX statement

Tags: excel, mdx, powerquery

In Excel Powerquery I have an MDX statement to query an analysis service. I tried introducing an iif function (which I understand should work like an if/else statement), but all it does is filter the results.

Here is a sample of my MDX statement shortened for readability and privacy reasons:

```
   SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Revenue] } ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { (
    [Account Information].[Name].[Name].ALLMEMBERS 
    * ........ 
    * iif([Service].[Level 3] = [Service].[Level 3].[Linux],[Service].[Level 3].[Linux], [Service].[Level 2]) ) } 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION,MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { 
[Geography].[Subsidiary].&[France] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Calendar].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Semester].&[FY18-H1] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Model])) WHERE ( [Calendar].[Fiscal Date Hierarchy].[Fiscal Semester].&[FY18-H1], [Geography].[Subsidiary].&[France] ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

The result right now is that all rows are filtered on ***[Service].[Level 3].[Linux]***.

The result that I want is that a column gets added with as a result ***[linux]*** if applicable to that row or ***[Service].[Level 2]*** in all other cases.

Comment: Not sure what your iif condition should do. Could you please provide a sql-style example or something else to reimplement for you?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem correct to me:

```
iif(
  [Service].[Level 3] = [Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 2]
)
```

If you are comparing members in `mdx` for equality then us the `IS` operator rather than `=`:

```
iif(
  [Service].[Level 3] IS [Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 2]
)
```

But this condition `[Service].[Level 3] IS [Service].[Level 3].[Linux]` will always return False, so you probably need to use the context via the `CURRENTMEMBER` function:

```
iif(
  [Service].CURRENTMEMBER IS [Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 3].[Linux]
 ,[Service].[Level 2]
)
```

but still I don't see how this fits `on rows` .... not much help

Why can you not give us all of the query?! The section marked `* ........ 
    *` doesn't help us help you